# How could I Type value inside my object to pass it as a props with react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I discovered TypeScript and I would like to use it into my react App, cause it's still possible but soon not.

So I was working on and from an hour I'm stuck on it... I would like to know what exactly wrong with it and what should I do?

To me it's a type error that's why I got 'Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never[]'.' but like said I'm a novice.

Someone there to help me to fix it and most important explain to me a little bit?

[Image of my code and the errors throws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSSbj.png)

Comment: You probably forgot to add Type definitions for the shape of your state. Therefore Typescript doesn't know what the shape of an item in `state.data` is.

See this link: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#class-components especially focus on where `MyState` is declared and make sure it matches the shape of your state. good luck!

Comment: Oh main you right! I forgot to type my state like this 'state: StateType' obviously doesn't work... Thx so much I understand my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify your const data as any type, like this: const data: any{} = ...

Comment: The problem wasn't exactly that but I used type 'any' thx to you and I know what you mean and I was stuck few minuit with it before so thx for the people who will read it ;)